# Many-to-many complex forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many

I'm not sure I am architecting this properly. I have a many-to-many relationship (Events <> Users) where I have a separate page (the Events show page) that connects the relationship of user to event. Because the relationship is not created on user or events page, I am not sure how to do this. Things I tried:

1. Create Event nested attribute form. The weird thing about this is that the form generates as many fields as there are relationships. So if I have an Event with 4 users, it would repeat 4 forms. That's not what I want, I just want to let the user add another Event <> User record relationship.
2. I tried creating a Event <> User form. This works well. I create a new controller and new route. The problem now is on the Create action. Once there is an error, if I try to render back to the old controller > action, the form partial pathing is all wrong because the browser already redirected to controller "event_user" URL.

So it looks for my partials in the EventUser folders instead of the original Event folders.

```
def create
    @event_user = EventUser.new(event_users_params)

    if @event_user.save
      redirect_to @event_user.event
    else          
      render 'events/show/'  # ERROR: Here it seems I need to redirect?
    end
  end
```

Potential solutions:

1. Use Redirect instead of Render. But I'll lose out on some local variables right?
2. Rearchitect this a different way where it never leaves the Event controller?

Answer (score 0):

This rails cast helped me set up a nested form so that a user could dynamically add and remove fields one at a time.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amT27SfNhKM.  If you post the code you used when trying to set up your nested form I might be able to help you figure out why it didn't work.